# How can I access a local FastAPI service with deployed with Skaffold?

Tags: python, kubernetes, fastapi, skaffold

Until now I developed Python applications locally using docker and docker-compose. Now I'd like to change my development workflow to use `skaffold` with `docker` as builder, with `kubectl` as deployer and with `minikube` for managing the local kubernetes cluster.

Let's say I've this docker based hello world for FastAPI:

project structure:

```
app/app.py
Dockerfile
```

app/app.py

```
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
def read_item(item_id: int, q: Optional[str] = None):
    return {"item_id": item_id, "q": q}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7

COPY ./app /app
```

If I run `docker build -t hello-fastapi .` and `docker run -p 80:80 hello-fastapi` I can access the service via `0.0.0.0` or `localhost`. I skip the `docker-compose` things here cause it does not matter w.r.t. the skaffold setup.

To use `skaffold` I have the exact same project structure and content but I added the skaffold + kubectl specific things (`skaffold.yaml`, `deployment.yaml`):

project structure:

```
app/app.py
k8s/deployment.yaml
Dockerfile
skaffold.yaml
```

k8s/deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fastapi-service
  labels:
    app: fastapi-service
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: fastapi-service
  selector:
    app: fastapi-service
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fastapi-service
  labels:
    app: fastapi-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fastapi-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fastapi-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fastapi-service
        image: fastapi-service
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

skaffold.yaml

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta10
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: fastapi-image
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - k8s/*
```

If I run `skaffold dev` everything seems to be fine:

```
Listing files to watch...
 - fastapi-service
Generating tags...
 - fastapi-service -> fastapi-service:latest
Some taggers failed. Rerun with -vdebug for errors.
Checking cache...
 - fastapi-service: Found Locally
Tags used in deployment:
 - fastapi-service -> fastapi-service:17659a877904d862184d7cc5966596d46b0765f1995f7abc958db4b3f98b8a35
Starting deploy...
 - service/fastapi-service created
 - deployment.apps/fastapi-service created
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
 - deployment/fastapi-service is ready.
Deployments stabilized in 2.165700782s
Press Ctrl+C to exit
Watching for changes...
[fastapi-service] Checking for script in /app/prestart.sh
[fastapi-service] Running script /app/prestart.sh
[fastapi-service] Running inside /app/prestart.sh, you could add migrations to this file, e.g.:
[fastapi-service] 
[fastapi-service] #! /usr/bin/env bash
[fastapi-service] 
[fastapi-service] # Let the DB start
[fastapi-service] sleep 10;
[fastapi-service] # Run migrations
[fastapi-service] alembic upgrade head
[fastapi-service] 
[fastapi-service] [2020-12-15 19:02:57 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[fastapi-service] [2020-12-15 19:02:57 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:80 (1)
[fastapi-service] [2020-12-15 19:02:57 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
[fastapi-service] [2020-12-15 19:02:57 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
...
```

However I cannot access the service via my web browser. How can I access the service from my local machine via e.g. the web browser?

**EDIT**:

According to `minikube service list` the service `fastapi-service` exists:

```
|----------------------|---------------------------|--------------|-----|
|      NAMESPACE       |           NAME            | TARGET PORT  | URL |
|----------------------|---------------------------|--------------|-----|
| default              | fastapi-service           | No node port |
| default              | kubernetes                | No node port |
| kube-system          | kube-dns                  | No node port |
| kubernetes-dashboard | dashboard-metrics-scraper | No node port |
| kubernetes-dashboard | kubernetes-dashboard      | No node port |
|----------------------|---------------------------|--------------|-----|
```

But I cannot access it via `curl $(minikube service fastapi-service --url)`:

```
curl: (3) Failed to convert  to ACE; string contains a disallowed character

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: service
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: default
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: has
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: no
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: node
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: port
```

Probably this is related to [Unable to get ClusterIP service url from minikube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60556096/unable-to-get-clusterip-service-url-from-minikube) . If I change `deployment.yaml` to

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fastapi-service
  labels:
    app: fastapi-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - targetPort: 80
      port: 80
  selector:
    app: fastapi-service
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fastapi-service
  labels:
    app: fastapi-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fastapi-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fastapi-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fastapi-service
        image: fastapi-service
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

accessing the service via `curl $(minikube service fastapi-service --url)` is successful:

```
{"message":"Hello world! From FastAPI running on Uvicorn with Gunicorn. Using Python 3.7"}
```

However I cannot access the service via the web browser.

Answer (score 2):

Use Skaffold [`--port-forward`](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/port-forwarding/) to enable automatic port fowarding of services and user-defined port-forwards.

Skaffold normally tries select a local port that is close to the remote port where possible.  But since port 80 is a protected port, Skaffold will choose a different local port.  You can explicitly [configure a port forward  your `skaffold.yaml`](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/port-forwarding/#user-defined-port-forwarding) to specify the local port.  Using user-defined port-forwards can help avoid potential confusion should you add other services later on.

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta10
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: fastapi-service
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - k8s/*
portForward:
  - resourceType: deployment
    resourceName: fastapi-service
    port: 80
    localPort: 9000
```

Instead of running `skaffold dev` run with `skaffold dev --port-forward`. Now you can access the service via `localhost:9000`.

You can also use `kubectl port-forward` to manually forward ports; Skaffold uses this same functionality to implement its port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

One can use `minikube service list` to get the IP and port of the service:

```
|----------------------|---------------------------|--------------|---------------------------|
|      NAMESPACE       |           NAME            | TARGET PORT  |            URL            |
|----------------------|---------------------------|--------------|---------------------------|
| default              | fastapi-service           |           80 | http://192.168.49.2:32205 |
| default              | kubernetes                | No node port |
| kube-system          | kube-dns                  | No node port |
| kubernetes-dashboard | dashboard-metrics-scraper | No node port |
| kubernetes-dashboard | kubernetes-dashboard      | No node port |
|----------------------|---------------------------|--------------|---------------------------|
```